# php mysql select function returning 0 but no error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, inner-join

Hi i want to select values between 2 number in php and i want to check if all of them exist in DB and there is no error but when i dump it is says array = 0

I am trying to get question and options in a single query using inner join and  select them between 2 numbers ,i check if they are in db with IN i get the first number and then i add 6 to it and then generate all numbers between them to use for IN

```
public function selectquestion($id){
    $max = $id + 4;//max selected value

    for ($i=$id; $i<=$max; $i++) {
        $arr[] = $i;//generates all numbers between min and max 
    }
    $range = implode(",",$arr);
    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT questions.value,questions.file,questions.img,options.option1,options.option2,options.option3,options.option4,options.answer 
                                FROM options 
                                INNER JOIN questions 
                                  ON questions.id = options.q_id 
                                WHERE questions.id >= '$id' 
                                  AND questions.id <= '$max' 
                                  AND questions.id IN ($range)");//selects all of questions and options where condition is true

    $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return$row;
}

var_dump($options = $obj->selectquestion(2));
```

i want it to show all questions and options but the output is 0

Comment: Why are you using both `IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` and `id >= 2 AND id <= 6`? They both should do the same thing.

Comment: This doesn't test if all the numbers exist, it just returns whichever ones exist.

Comment: This is PDO? If so `prepare` doesn't `execute`. You also are misusing prepared statements, parameterize.

Comment: You're not calling `$sql->execute()`

Comment: Did you tried to run that query directly in your database? If so, it returns the data you want?

Comment: Also  your `for($i=$id; $i<=$max; $i++) {` can just be `range($id, $id + 4)`

Comment: oh my god,i've been working on it for 5 days,im an idiot thank you

Comment: FYI, if you're not binding parameters you can use `->query` and it will execute the SQL immediately. But you should definitely learn to use bound parameters, not substitute variables into the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you never execute the query. You should also be using a prepared statement instead of injecting your variables directly into the query.

It also makes little sens to check both for an ID to be greater than minimum, less than maximum *and* within that range. You can simplify your query and use a proper prepared statement by just checking the `BETWEEN` instead. Also, by using aliases you can shorten down the columns you select.

```
public function selectquestion($id){
    $max = $id + 4; //max selected value

    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT q.value, q.file, q.img, 
                                       o.option1, o.option2, o.option3, o.option4, o.answer 
                                FROM options o
                                INNER JOIN questions q
                                    ON q.id = o.q_id 
                                WHERE q.id BETWEEN ? AND ?");
    $sql->execute([$id, $max]);
    return $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the execute after the prepare statement. Otherwise it will not execute your query.

```
public function selectquestion($id){
    $max = $id + 4;//max selected value
    $params = array();
    $arr = array();
    $count = 1;
    for($i=$id; $i<=$max; $i++) {
        $arr[$count] = $i;//generates all numbers between min and max 
        $params[$count] = ':p_'.$count;
        $count++;
    }
    $range_param = implode(",",$params);
    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT questions.value,questions.file,questions.img,options.option1,options.option2,options.option3,options.option4,options.answer FROM options INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id = options.q_id WHERE questions.id >= :id AND questions.id <= :max AND questions.id IN ($range_param)");//selects all of questions and options where condition is true
    $sql->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':max', $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    foreach($arr as $key => $a){
        $sql->bindParam(':p_'.$key, $arr[$key], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return$row;
}
var_dump($options = $obj->selectquestion(2));
```

Comment: This is not using a proper prepared statement! You use `prepare()`, but you never bind the values! Big no-no!

Comment: @Qirel you're right.. Now i have updated my answer to bind the parameters